# Global variable not passed down in stack - IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, global-variables, eval

I am working on a legacy application that is breaking in Internet Explorer.  It has the following code:

Script 1:  `/* Call script 2 */; x.a(b)`

Script 2:  `eval(script3)`

Script 3:  `var x = x || {}; x.a = function(){ ... }`

In Firefox, this works as expected.

In internet explorer, however, it fails by saying "x is undefined" (this is massively simplified).  I traced it back to this point in the code and noted that `x` is defined in script 3 but then going back down in the stack to script 2 it loses its availability/scope (I tested this by putting console.log statements in both - IE was ok with the one in script 3 but crashed for the one in script 2).

What about internet explorer and/or the `eval()` function causes this to happen and what are my options for fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not set up a test and see for yourself?

Here is one: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3bf5/

It seems to work fine in IE7+.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change Script 3 to `var x; x = x || {}; x.a = function(){ ... }`

This might've caused due to preemptive usage of the variable before it's been declared in this case variable **x**.

The fact that variable x is unavailable in **Script 2** is because the `eval()` method failed abruptly with "**x is undefined**"

Actually I understood only a lil' bit from the piece of code that refers **Script 3**

If I could get a glimpse of it, then I might be of better help to you than now.

Hope this helps